# can we build application using es6 for Vue framework

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuex, es6-class

Im building an application using  **vue js framework** I need to know do I go for es6 in vue framework .Is it good enough to go with **es6** as its in **es5** I need to know that it must go for **[ vue +vuex+ es6 ]**.
Are there links or sample examples where i can learn vue in es6 as vue.org provide es5 features only
Else must be preferred let me now  as m newbie i have no much idea
Please lemme know ur guidance is much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Whether you should go for `es5` or `es6` is entire up to you. Because what you can achieve in `es6` can also be achieved by `es5`. But `es6` comes with new feature that are very useful. So I would say go for es6.

Comment: Regarding setting up project and deployment you can follow this links 

1) https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html

2) https://itnext.io/develop-awesome-webapps-using-vuejs-webpack-bda08ebb691c

Comment: Are there links or sample examples where i can learn vue in es6 as vue.org provide es5 features only i wanna use es6 itelf

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build an application with vue.js, es6 is good, but you'll need babel and webpack.

I do all my development with es6, sometimes you will need some polyfills for some so older browsers.

If your're a real newbie, I'll recommend to start with the cli of vue.js or even a nuxt.js, which is a very nice  vue framework to get you started. They all have babel and webpack preconfigured for you.

Have fun!

Comment: to vue m new. Are there links or sample examples where i can learn vue in es6 as vue.org provide es5 features only i wanna use es6 for vue . then definetly ill enjoy

Comment: @Tested, Well I would recommend you "Vue JS 2 - The Complete Guide (incl. Vue Router & Vuex)" video from  Udemy. It's an excellent guide to Vue JS and definitely worth each dollar.